# Get admin menu link

Tags: menus, admin, navigation

Is there any way I can get the menu link for admins?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/edit_post_link

Similarly to the `edit_post_link()` that returns the edit link for loggedin Admins
I would like to do something similar for the `edit menu` if there is anything like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `admin_url('nav-menus.php');`

This function can be used to get url's for any admin screen, please check out the codex for more information http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/admin_url